# Recommended approach to avoid duplicating username in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

When a new user attempts to register on my application at present, part of the validation process is to check against the database (MongoDB) whether the username and email are already in use. This validation process is part of my application logic.

I would like to know whether it's possible/better to attempt to save the user without these validation checks and let the DB detect an error (due to duplicated email address or username) which I could then handle.

If so, how could I handle these errors so that I could handle each (username and email). Something in the fashion of...

```
err := c.Database.C("users").Insert(&user);
if err != nil {
    //check whether issue is with email or username or both
}
```

Comment: In all honesty, it depends on what you really want to do here. An "unique" index on the properties would result in an error on an insertion attempt where the combination of those values exist, and then you can "handle" that. On the other hand, if you want to be able to address "unique" properties and maybe perform some action on match or otherwise "insert" the new data, then ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) behavior might be what you need. So it is all about how you intend to react to a "duplicate" when it occurs.

Comment: Provided that the two attributes are indexed, I don't see *that* much difference between waiting for a duplication error vs. manual validating. One point to take into consideration here is the readability/logic of the code structure - why detect/expect an error when you can prevent it from occurring in the first place?

Comment: Part of my thinking was efficieny though it may be negligible - I'm having to query twice to see if email exists then username.

Comment: @tommyd456 Well there should be clear diver methods for creating an index, and the general principles are well documented. But "spefically" here I am also asking you to be "specific", which you are presently not doing. "Unique" is either the "combination" of "username" and "email" properties **or** it is one or the other that needs to be identified as "unique". So you could be a lot clearer in your intended purpose here and "pick" one of these options as you action statement for what it is you really want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Guess the unique index should work for you (if the upinsert does not fit the need).
Setting those indices in mongo command works fine, another way is to use mgo.EnsureIndex in your code, a quick example can be found at https://gist.github.com/border/3489566.
According to the official document, once the index is successfully created, the EnsureIndex won't be contacting server unless the indices were dropped.

> Once EnsureIndex returns successfully, following requests for the same >index will not contact the server unless Collection.DropIndex is used to >drop the same index, or Session.ResetIndexCache is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid duplicates with an [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique). To create such an index in the mongo shell, use:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { name: 1 }, { unique: true } );
db.collection.createIndex( { email: 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

When you then insert a document which violates the uniqueness constraint, you will receive an error result. Unfortunately you will have to parse the text of the error message to find out which one of your indexes was violated. `err.errmsg` will be a string in this format:

`insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: [index]  dup key: [value]"`

Be aware of a strange quirk of unique indexes. Unique indexes consider "field doesn't exist" as a separate unique value. So it allows exactly one document in the collection where the field is missing. So make sure that all required fields are filled before sending the document to the database.